# Change GCC version used by bjam

Tags: macos, gcc, boost, bjam

I am trying to build a library (luabind) with bjam. I came across an error and it seems like the problem is that I need to compile with gcc 4.2, but the default on this computer (Mac OSX) is 4.0. I would prefer not to go around changing links in system directories, is there a way to specify to bjam to use gcc4.2 rather than just gcc?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's described [in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html). You should have:

```
using gcc : 4.2 : g++-42 ;
```

in your user-config.jam and "bjam toolset=gcc-4.2" on the command line

Answer (score 1):

Try running bjam with these options:

--toolset=gcc --toolset-root=/path/to/gcc/4.2